# How to find out what trusted CA's are preinstalled for AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, ssl-certificate

For my AWS Lambda, I need to know what trusted CA's are there. I want to have a list of CA's so for a service the lambda tries to reach it can trust it without installing any new certs.

Comment: why you required this ? this is container based service.

Comment: What language are you developing in?  Java, for example, maintains it's own list.

Comment: @aviboy2006 it's not exactly a requirement, but for now, I would like to know what CA's are already there.

Comment: @stdunbar I am using Java.

Comment: @SándorBakos yes, lamda is a client in https call, but to not reject server it reaches the certificate used by a service has to trusted by the lambda.

Comment: You can have more info here [link1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Reference.html) and [link2](https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find out yourself:

```
public class PrintCAInfo implements RequestStreamHandler {

    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("[");

        try {
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory =
                    TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);

            for( TrustManager trustManager: trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()) {
                X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager)trustManager;
                for(X509Certificate x509Certificate: x509TrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers() ) {
                    stringBuilder.append("{");
                    stringBuilder.append("\"subjectDN\":\"");
                    stringBuilder.append(x509Certificate.getSubjectDN().toString().replaceAll("\"", ""));
                    stringBuilder.append("\"},");
                }
            }

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(stringBuilder.substring(0, stringBuilder.length() - 1));

        stringBuilder.append("]");

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        writer.write(stringBuilder.toString());
        logger.log(stringBuilder.toString());

        writer.close();
    }
}
```

This returns (and logs) a very simple JSON body:

```
[
  {
    "subjectDN": "CN=Amazon RDS eu-south-1 CA, OU=Amazon RDS, O=Amazon Web Services, Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US"
  },
  {
    "subjectDN": "CN=Hongkong Post Root CA 1, O=Hongkong Post, C=HK"
  },
  {
    "subjectDN": "CN=SecureTrust CA, O=SecureTrust Corporation, C=US"
  },
  {
    "subjectDN": "CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - EC1, OU=(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only, OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms, O=Entrust, Inc., C=US"
  },
  {
    "subjectDN": "CN=DigiCert Global Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US"
  },
  {
    "subjectDN": "OU=Security Communication RootCA1, O=SECOM Trust.net, C=JP"
  },
```